# ¿Cómo pasar los valores de una fila HTML a otra pagina web que es una plantilla?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo dos páginas la primera tiene una tabla HTML y el último dato es la liga que toma los datos y abre una página que es cert.html, un certificado donde quiero acomodar los valores de la fila con formato.

Actualmente no me pasa los datos solo se abre la página y punto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        //  function myFunction() {
        //    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=600,height=400");
        //   myWindow.document.write("valores+=$(this).html()+"\n");
        //   var valores="";
        //  $(this).parents("tr").find("td").each(function(){
        //               valores+=$(this).html()+"\n";
        //                                                  });
        //                              });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".boton").click(function() {

                var myWindow = window.open("cert.html", "_blank", "width=1090,height=860");
                var valores = "";

                // Obtenemos todos los valores contenidos en los <td> de la fila
                // seleccionada
                $(this).parents("tr").each(function() {
                    valores += $(this).html() + "\n";
                    //valores = valores + "</br></br>";
                });

                //  myWindow.document.write(valores+ "<body background='plantilla.png'/>");
                //       myWindow.document.write("<span class='green'>The score you entered is:"   + valores +   ".Your letter grade is: B!</span>");
                //      myWindow.document.write(valores);

                myWindow.document.write("imgtext.html");

                // alert(valores);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        myWindow {
            background-image: url("cedulalmma.jpg");
        }

        .boton {
            border: 1px solid #808080;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 2px 5px;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>val 1</td>
            <td>val 2</td>
            <td>val 3</td>
            <td class="boton"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>val 4</td>
            <td>val 5</td>
            <td>val 6</td>
            <td class="boton"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>val 7</td>
            <td>val 8</td>
            <td>val 9</td>
            <td class="boton"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: estuve probando varias formas y poniendo myWindow.document.write(valores); en vez de myWindow.document.write("imgtext.html"); como lo tienes arriba, al pulsar el boton de la tabla ya salen los valores en la pantalla nueva.
Un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias por el apoyo, me dejarías ver tu código, porque hice el cambio pero aunque deje la pagina del link vacía, al abrirse desde la fila se queda vacío, no inserta los valores de la fila en la pagina que en este caso es cert.html. gracias